# Error in Web scraping program with Python using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I've written some web scraping code based on online tutorials and am getting an error. My code matches almost exactly what's there online but still seem to be getting an error. Can someone please help. Based on the error type, it seems to be related to filename and the path. I've tried various combinations there but am still getting an error.

Have copied my code below.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = 'https://www.newegg.com/Video-Cards-Video-Devices/Category/ID-38?Tpk=graphics%20cards'

uClient = uReq(my_url)
page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

page_soup = soup(page_html, "html.parser")

containers = page_soup.finaAll("div", {"class":"item-container"})

filename = "C:\\Users\\_Alekhine_\\Python\\products.csv"
f = open(filename, "w")

headers = "brand, product_name, shipping\n"
f.write(" ")

for container in containers:
    brand = container.div.div.a.img["title"]

    title_container = container.findAll("a", {"class": "item-title"})
    product_name = title_container[0].text

    shipping_container = container.findAll("li", {"class": "price-ship"})
    shipping = shipping_container[0].text.strip()

    print("brand: " + brand)
    print("product_name: " + product_name)
    print("shipping: " + shipping)

    f.write(brand + "" + product_name.replace(",", "") + "" + shipping + "\n")

    f.close()
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Don't you feel that is something important to mention?

Answer (score 0):

As you didn't post your error, I can just assume from your error description that the path you specifiy in line 14 doesn't exist. `open` fails if the file's path doesn't exist, even in write mode. Try creating the directory `C:\Users\_Alekhine_\Python` first.

You can do so in Python (3.2+):

```
import os
os.makedirs(path, exist_ok=True)
```

Btw, there is also a typo in your code sample (line 12 should be `findAll` instead of `finaAll`), but I assume that this is not the error you described.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The path in the C drive does exist. The error message I was getting was - TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable.           The code is now creating a CSV file. Thanks again.